# Mutlisite in wordpress is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created wordpress multi-site.

but when i tried open 
example.com/au. it gives me server 404 error. 
I already enable mod_rewrite and start the apache service.
I am using ubuntu14.0 and my root directory is /var/www.

wp-config.

```
   define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'eplate.cloudapp.net');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

and .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
Any idea.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you did not proces the steps provided by the Multisite setup in which you have to create an .htaccess file with a predefined config provided by the installation. I believe you can find them again when you login at /wp-admin/ under "Network"

Comment: i had made changes in .htaccess file already . it was not working

Comment: Did you choose the subdomain setup or the folder setup for new sites?

Comment: Could you edit your post by adding your wp-config (exclude your DB credentials!) and .htaccess file?

Comment: When I look at your config it says `define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/');`. This should mean that you can access your site trough localhost/wordpress/sitename instead of localhost/sitename

Comment: Do i need to change any server settings ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70556/discussion-between-hitu-bansal-and-niels-van-renselaar).